# Run Time error 91, when using the find method

Tags: excel, vba, find, runtime-error

I was hoping you could help on an error I keep getting - I'm trying to fix a data error that occurs occasionally in my report by removing said line and then resorting the data and ensuring all the formulas are correct.

I ran the macro recorder and used that to help build the below code - everything worked fine when I ran the code from the recorder but now I have tried to personalise it to my workbook (i.e., add in workbook names) I keep getting a

> runtime 91 error at this line

```
cell = data.Range("A1:A400").Find(What:="Date", lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Any help around what I have done to cause the error so that I can avoid it in the future would be really useful!

```
Sub RemoveLine()
    Dim del, dr As Workbook
    Set dr = ThisWorkbook
    Set del = Workbooks("Delivery Data.xls")

    Dim rep, inf, data As Worksheet
    Set rep = dr.Sheets("Report")
    Set inf = dr.Sheets("Info")
    Set data = dr.Sheets("Data")

    Dim r1, r2, r3, r4, row01 As Long

    Dim nu, na As String

    nu = inf.Range("C7").Text
    na = inf.Range("C4").Text

    cell = data.Range("A1:A400").Find(What:="Date", lookat:=xlWhole)           
    MsgBox cell

    If Not cell Is Nothing Then          
        row01 = cell.Row
        data.Range("A" & row01 & ":S" & row01).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        data.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        data.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A21"), _
          SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        With data.Sort
            .SetRange Range("A2:S21")
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With


        'FORMULAS                    
        Dim st1, st2, st3, st4, st5, st6 As String

        st1 = "=IF(Data!A2="""", """", Data!A2)"
        st2 = "=IF(Data!C2="""", """", Data!C2)"
        st3 = "=IF(Data!G2="""", """", Data!G2)"
        st4 = "=IF(F3="""", """", G3/$C$10)"
        st5 = "=IF(E27="""", """", Data!G2)"
        st6 = "=IF(C27="""", """", G27/Info!$C$10)"

        With inf
            .Range("E3:E100").Formula = st1
            .Range("F3:F100").Formula = st2
            .Range("G3:G100").Formula = st3
            .Range("H3:H100").Formula = st4
        End With

        With rep
            .Range("B27:C62").Formula = st1
            .Range("E27:E62").Formula = st2
            .Range("G27:G62").Formula = st5
            .Range("J27:J62").Formula = st6
        End With       
    End If            
End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that `Dim del, dr As Workbook` only declares `dr As Workbook` but `del As Variant`. In VBA you must specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim del As Workbook, dr As Workbook`. Accordingly for all your other declarations. Additionally I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is probably due to the fact that `cell` is not declared, and you are not using the `Set` keyword. Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa195730(v=office.11)#find-method-as-it-applies-to-the-range-object), `Find` on a `Range` returns a `Range` (or `Nothing`), so you should have:

```
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = data.Range("A1:A400").Find(What:="Date", LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I've managed to solve the issue by declaring cell as a variant and running the find method in a with block - this seems to have fixed everything.

However my named arguments are still in parentheses as this is how I saw the code formatted online - I'll remove these now!

Comment: @Aurel Bílý: If you call a function (and want to get the return value), you **need** to put the arguments in parentheses, else the compiler will complain. And yes, you can use named arguments in parentheses